# Neos CMS error Call to undefined function GuzzleHttp\Psr7\str()

Tags: neoscms, neos-server

i'm very new in Neos CMS. I install Neos CMS according to this tutorial https://neutroncloud.in/docs/how-to-install-neos-cms-on-ubuntu/. I've been struggling for 3 days for install it. When i finally set it up, i've set everything up. And after lunch, it's shows this error

```
Call to undefined function GuzzleHttp\Psr7\str()
Exception Code  0
Exception Type  Error
Thrown in File   
Data/Temporary/Development/Cache/Code/Flow_Object_Classes/Neos_Fusion_FusionObjects_HttpR 
esponseImplementation.php
Line    62
Original File    
Packages/Application/Neos.Fusion/Classes/FusionObjects/HttpResponseImplementation.php
```

And here is screenshot of the content site of my neos
[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rz4Yf.png)

Please help me :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently you are using the guzzle/psr-7 in version 2, wich is currently not supported (although we are working on it and it will be very soon).

do a

```
$ composer require guzzlehttp/psr7 "^1.8.2"
$ composer update
```

to fix that issue. It was also fixed with the latest FLow bugfix release which was released yesterday (https://github.com/neos/flow-development-collection/pull/2502).

PS: It is not worth it struggling for days with Neos problems. We have a slack channel (https://slack.neos.io/) and a vivid community which likes to help you.